# DRY up CSS - multiple parents to one child

Tags: css, css-selectors, dry

I have several hierarchies separately listed out below where first selector is the parent div, second is the image item within the div. But could I combine these somehow?

```
.outdoors .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.snowsports .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stripe .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.twilio .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rental_requests .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the parent element doesn't matter, then you could simply use:

```
.how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Otherwise, you would have to combine the selectors. The simplest form would be:

```
.outdoors .how-to-image,
.snowsports .how-to-image,
.stripe .how-to-image,
.twilio .how-to-image,
.rental_requests .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

Aside from that, there is no other way to simplify it. Even if you were to use [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/), the same would be outputted.

```
.outdoors, .snowsports, .stripe, .twilio, .rental_requests {
  .how-to-image {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.outdoors .how-to-image,
.snowsports .how-to-image,
.stripe .how-to-image,
.twilio .how-to-image,
.rental_requests .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the pseudo-class selector [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) to deduplicate the common child selector when there are multiple parents:

```css
:is(.outdoors, .snowsports, .stripe, .twilio, .rental_requests) .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The code above is equivalent to:

```css
.outdoors .how-to-image,
.snowsports .how-to-image,
.stripe .how-to-image,
.twilio .how-to-image,
.rental_requests .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

### References

- https://web.dev/css-is-and-where
- https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can combine selectors by separating them with a comma:

```
.outdoors .how-to-image, .snowsports .how-to-image, .stripe .how-to-image, .twilio .how-to-image, .rental_requests .how-to-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And depending on the HTML hierarchy you may even be able to narrow it down further.